# In accordance with IRS regulations filing of an FBAR is required in my case

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-accounts

I have approximately $26,600.00 in a foreign bank account...this account is used for daily living expenses. I am wondering when reporting this on IRS Form 8938 if I will have to pay US Taxes on this money? I pay Federal income tax on my Military Retired Pay and Social Security payments already. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FBAR (aka FinCEN form 114) and (IRS) form 8938 are _different_ and either or both can apply to a US person's foreign accounts. If your _total_ is $27k, 8938 does not apply but FBAR does. See https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements

Answer (score 10):

The FBAR reporting does not result in any tax liability; you have nothing to worry about.
You don't pay taxes for *having* money, you pay taxes for *making* money (=income).

The main reason the IRS wants to know about foreign accounts is to follow illegal money streams.